# matplotlib の lsim の使い方

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

私はPythonでmatplotlibを使って制御工学の勉強をしている者です。今回はlsimの使い方について質問させていただきます。

・まず認識から述べます。

lsimは線形システムの応答を出力する関数です。引数に、システム、時間、入力信号、初期状態を求めます。

・分からない点

lsimそれだけを実行してもグラフがプロットされると聞きましたが、僕の以下のコードではなりません。実行すると多量の数値が出てくるので、それをplotに突っ込んで初めてグラフがでます。
また、プロットするときは

```
y,_,_=lsim(P,Ud,Td,0)
```

のように、三つの返り値を設定してやらないと動きません。これはなぜでしょうか？おまけに、このコードでは、yは二本の波形が出てきます。
lsimに三つの返り値を設定しなければいけない理由、そしてそれぞれは何を表しているのか教えてください。

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from numpy.random import *
from control.matlab import *

A="0,1;-4,-5"
B="0;1"
C="1,0;0,1"
D="0;0"
P=ss(A,B,C,D)

w=np.pi
n=1

Td=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,0.01)
Ud=np.cos(n*w*Td)

y,_,_=lsim(P,Ud,Td,0)

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].plot(Td,Ud)
ax[1].plot(y)
```

Comment: `lsim`は`matplotlib`ではなく`control.matlab`のメソッドのようですね。[control.matlab.lsim](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.3/generated/control.matlab.lsim.html), [python control での lsim の使い方](https://teratail.com/questions/201607), [PythonControlで正弦波に対する応答を求める。](https://qiita.com/nnn112358/items/5de7a5664bb7668ed2e7) 他に`scipy`の物もあるようですが、こちらは戻り値が違うので別物のようです。[scipy.signal.lsim](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lsim.html)

Comment: 元であろう`MATLAB`の解説を見ると、2本の波形は入力信号とシステム応答と思われます。[システム応答のプロット](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/control/examples/plotting-system-responses.html), [lsim](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lsim.html) 「lsimそれだけを実行してもグラフがプロットされる」というのはMATLABの開発環境とかツール上の話か、Pythonでも何か同様の環境の話では？

Comment: ありがとうございます。例えば、帰ってくる二本の波形のうち、一本だけをプロットしたい場合はどうすれば良いのでしょうか？僕のあげたコードだとplotにyだけ突っ込んでも時間軸も、2本目の波形も同時に返してきます。

Comment: `print(type(y))`と`print(y)`してみればわかりますが、`y`は2次元のndarrayです。こちらの記事 [NumPy配列ndarrayの要素・行・列を取得（抽出）、代入](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-select-element-row-column-array/) にあるように`d0 = y[:, 0]`, `d1 = y[:, 1]`とすれば抽出できるのでは？ 数値は`Ud`とは同じではないようですが、それを`ax[0].plot(Td,d0)`, `ax[1].plot(Td,d1)`としてみれば分けて表示出来るでしょう。

Comment: なるほど、二次元ですか。二本の波の物理的な意味は「それぞれの初期状態からの応答」ということでしょうかね?

Comment: yをprintすると確かに二種類の数字を含んだリストのリストのようなものが出てきました。ここで新たな疑問は、ax[1].plot(y)のコードだけで時間軸もx軸にプロット出来ているという点です。これはなぜでしょうか？

Comment: 表示された`X`軸の目盛りとか[matplotlib.pyplot.plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)の仕様を見ると、パラメータが1個だけ指定なら`Y`軸データを指定したことになり、`X`軸にはデータのインデックス(何番目であるか)が使われるようです。

Comment: なるほど。yだけの入力ですと、箱の中の数値と、それが何番目かを対応させるのですね。とても納得しました。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントのやり取りで解決したようなので、回答として投稿しておきます。

`lsim`は`matplotlib`ではなく`control.matlab`のメソッドのようですね。
[control.matlab.lsim](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.3/generated/control.matlab.lsim.html)
[python control での lsim の使い方](https://teratail.com/questions/201607)
[PythonControlで正弦波に対する応答を求める。](https://qiita.com/nnn112358/items/5de7a5664bb7668ed2e7)

他に`scipy`にも同名のメソッドがあり、機能としては類似らしいですが、こちらは戻り値の内容や並び方が違うので別物のようです。
[scipy.signal.lsim](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lsim.html)

---

「三つの返り値を設定してやらないと動きません。これはなぜでしょうか？」というのは、以下のようにそれがこのメソッドの仕様だからです。

> control.matlab.lsim(sys, U=0.0, T=None, X0=0.0)
>
> Returns:
>
> - yout (array) – Response of the system.
> - T (array) – Time values of the output.
> - xout (array) – Time evolution of the state vector.

そして「三つの返り値...それぞれは何を表しているのか」については、上記`control.matlab.lsim`仕様の記述と、名前から推測できる元であろう`MATLAB`の解説で以下のように記述されています。
[lsim](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lsim.html)

> 推定に使用したものと同じ入力データと推定コマンドによって返された初期状態を使用して、sys の応答をシミュレートします。
>
> ```
> [y,t,x] = lsim(sys,z.InputData,[],x0);
> ```
>
> ここで、y はシステム応答、t はシミュレーションに使用される時間ベクトル、x は状態軌跡です。

---

「おまけに、このコードでは、yは二本の波形が出てきます。」については同様に`MATLAB`の解説を見ると、2本の波形は入力信号とシステム応答と思われます。
[システム応答のプロット](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/control/examples/plotting-system-responses.html)

> lsim コマンドを使用すると、任意の信号 (たとえば正弦波) に対する応答をシミュレートすることもできます。入力信号は灰色、システムの応答は青色で表示されます。

「lsimそれだけを実行してもグラフがプロットされる」というのは上記ページのようにMATLABの開発環境とかツール上の話か、Pythonでも何か同様の環境の話と思われます。

---

「帰ってくる二本の波形のうち、一本だけをプロットしたい場合はどうすれば良いのでしょうか？」について：

`print(type(y))`と`print(y)`してみればわかりますが、`y`は2次元の`numpy.ndarray`です。
こちらの記事[NumPy配列ndarrayの要素・行・列を取得（抽出）、代入](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-select-element-row-column-array/)にあるように

```
d0 = y[:, 0]
d1 = y[:, 1]
```

とすれば抽出できるのでは？

数値は`Ud`とは同じではないようですが、それを

```
ax[0].plot(Td,d0)
ax[1].plot(Td,d1)
```

としてみれば分けて表示出来るでしょう。

---

「ax[1].plot(y)のコードだけで時間軸もx軸にプロット出来ているという点です。これはなぜでしょうか？」について：

表示されたグラフの`X`軸の目盛りとか[matplotlib.pyplot.plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)の仕様を見ると、以下の`plot(y)  # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1`のようにパラメータが1個だけ指定されたなら`Y`軸データを指定したことになり、`X`軸にはデータのインデックス(何番目であるか)が使われるようです。

> ```
> >>> plot(x, y)        # plot x and y using default line style and color
> >>> plot(x, y, 'bo')  # plot x and y using blue circle markers
> >>> plot(y)           # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1
> >>> plot(y, 'r+')     # ditto, but with red plusses
> ```